# Activity is not being launched after click in a Notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

a have tried 8 versions of the following code, but the Home activity is not being launched when I click the notification.

Here is the code (it's inside of a Service)

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.alert);
builder.setContentTitle("");
builder.setContentText("Running in Background");
builder.setOngoing(true); 

IntenIntenticationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,notificationIntent, 0);
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please the code below?

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.alert);
builder.setContentTitle("");
builder.setContentText("Running in Background");
builder.setOngoing(true);
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Comment: You are a amazing!! I have been trying for hours to get this to work. I think it was the setContentIntent that I was missing.